# Complex pathing route

Tags: c#, algorithm, math

```
                      L->|
  A -> B              ^  |
  |__> C -> D-> G->X--|  |
       K    |_> T  |  |_>Z
       |___________|
```

I hope this small drawing helps convey what I'm trying to do.

I have a list of 7,000 locations, each with an undefined, but small number of doors. Each door is a bridge between both locations.

Referencing the diagram above, how would I go about finding the quickest route through the doors to get from A to Z?

I don't need full on source, just psuedo code would be fine.

Obviously you can take A -> B ->C -> D -> G -> X -> L -> Z, 
but the shortest route is A -> B -> C -> K -> X -> Z.

Comment: By undefined do you mean dynamic?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Represent your locations as nodes and the doors as edges in a graph.  Then apply some rather standard [shortest path algorithm(s)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path_problem) and you're done.

Answer (score 2):

Look up [Pathfinding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pathfinding) algorithms on Wikipedia. You basically build up a series of nodes and connections between them, and the algorithm works through them finding a way from the start to a goal.

Answer (score 2):

You can suppose that each room is a node and each door is a node and the problem will become finding shortest path in graph which you can find with [Dijkstra's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) for example